# How can a more dynamic look of graphics be achieved in Flash CS 5.5?

Tags: color, flash

I have two graphics each moving on a separate guide (path) on the main timeline. Both graphics have their own timelines with multiple layers of other graphics which are animated further to perform simple up and down movements. The nested graphics move nicely on the same paths of the parent graphics while performing their own movements...

(Two airplanes making different turns while the parachuters are jumping out from the back)

At the moment, I'm only familiar and confident with animating graphics and not movie clips but, what I would like to achieve is to make them look more dynamic and textured by ...well... adding filters and such :D

Are graphics in Flash CS5.5 limited to only the primary color panel or can I apply some other tricks?
Can be more done before they are turned to symbols - while they are still just shapes?

Since I have a deadline for the animation I have to postpone learning everything about movie clips...

Any guidance would probably save me from lots of frustrating hours...

Best regards